# How to use [formControlName] with mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

In the Angular Material documentation, they say `[formControlName]` cannot be used with a `mat-checkbox`. How can I create checkboxes dynamically according to an array of values and get checkbox value using reactive forms? Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you misunderstood docs. formControlName work with mat-checkbox and you can create them dynamically:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <mat-checkbox
    [formControlName]="field.name"
    [labelPosition]="field.labelPosition"
    [disabled]="field.disabled"
    [checked]="field.checked"
  >
   {{field.label}}
  </mat-checkbox>
 </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: you need'nt use `[checked]` (the value checked is the value of the formControl)

Comment: Also, You shouldn't use `[disabled]` while using the reactive form